# how to make prediction using tensorflowjs (converted from keras model) model in javascript?

Tags: tensorflow

I have an face detection model converted from keras to tensorflow js .I am using this model in javascript but its make wrong prediction..

I got prediction data in format of tensor  like  :Tensor
[[0.8926722, 0.1591875],],
but I don't know how to use this to make right prediction .